# channel.invokeMethod() does not work in FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage();

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-native

In Flutter
Calling a native method like this `_channel.invokeMethod()` in a

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);`

gives exception

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method wakeupscreen on channel flutter_native)`

here is my _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler()

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  await Firebase
      .initializeApp(); //make sure firebase is initialized before using it (showCallkitIncoming)

  wakeupscreen();

}

// wakeupscreen() func -- this is a global function so does not require any class instance to run

wakeupscreen() async {
  try {
    const platform = MethodChannel('flutter_native');
    await platform.invokeMethod('wakeupscreen');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("Failed to invoke the method: '${e.message}'.");
  }
}
```

I tried using this same wakeupscreen() function in a normal code :

```
InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
                      wakeupscreen();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("wakeup in 5 sec"),
                ),
```

And it works perfectly as expected when calling it normally, but as soon as the same function is called in `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

In main.dart, set up a method channel to handle messages from the background isolate:

```
// Inside main.dart

MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('flutter_native');

// Set up method channel to communicate with background isolate
_channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
  if (call.method == 'wakeupscreen') {
    wakeupscreen(); // Call your wakeupscreen function here
  }
});
```

Remove method channel initialization from the wakeupscreen function:

```
// Remove this line from the wakeupscreen function
const platform = MethodChannel('flutter_native');
```

These changes ensure that the method channel is appropriately configured to manage messages from the background isolate and that the wakeupscreen function is invoked as required.

Comment: can you be more clear about the flow and which code to place where because i'm not aware that method channels can be used to communicate with a background isolate, so i'm bit confused as to what you are trying to say.

Comment: Please review the Firebase Messaging package on pub.dev and explore its examples for better understanding. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: can you point out any specific code/ file in example related to your answer.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ChanakaDev/flutter-firebase-push-notifications-complete-guide-fae42c88f32a

Comment: Literally you have just mentioned an article that shows you how to implement fcm. I already have done that if you just go through my question you would know. I have provided the info in detail about the problem. So unless and until you have a proper solution please stop writing answers just for the sake of it. PLEASE!

Comment: Okay no problem Thank you, and I wish you all the best.